# How to configure CRON using Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, cron, server-setup

I have created a module with CRON job but no CRON set on my server how we can set CRON in Magento 2 using SSH.

Comment: I hope my answer solve your query, Let me know if still issue.

Comment: If my answer solves your concern then there is green right tick mark, hit that tickmark for right answer that will help future readers.

Comment: were you able to solve your issue?

Answer (score 2):

There is pretty good documentation on dev docs regarding this ;

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html

Please follow this. Ping me if you have any queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure using the command `crontab -e`, then change the snippet below to follow your structure of files and folders:

```
#~ MAGENTO START
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento cron:run 2>&1 | grep -v Ran jobs by schedule >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/magento.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/update/cron.php >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/setup.cron.log
#~ MAGENTO END
```

Reference: [Magento DevDocs - Configure and run cron](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html)

Comment: installing new cron tab show in ssh

Comment: when i run the cmd php bin/magento cron:run i am getting the error Undefined index: jobs in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-cron/M
  odel/Config/Converter/Db.php on lin

Answer (score 0):

**Create the cron job**

To create a cron job for the Magento file system owner, enter the following command as a user with root privileges:

```
crontab -u <Magento file system owner user name> -e
```

For example,

```
crontab -u magento_user -e
```

A text editor displays. (You might need to choose a text editor first.)

```
\* * * * * <path to php binary> <magento install dir>/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> <magento install dir>/var/log/magento.cron.log

\* * * * * <path to php binary> <magento install dir>/update/cron.php >> <magento install dir>/var/log/update.cron.log

\* * * * * <path to php binary> <magento install dir>/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> <magento install dir>/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

where

`<path to php binary>` is the absolute file system path to your PHP binary
`<magento install dir>` is the directory in which you installed the Magento software; for example, /var/www

```
| grep -v "Run jobs by schedule"
```

[Reference](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html)